# PL/SQL looping through collection and adding to another collection query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code but i do not know what is the best practice in regards to looping through collection and adding the each item to a Varray.

Below is my current code:

```
DECLARE
TYPE student_arraytype IS TABLE OF student%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
student_array student_arraytype;

--varray type
 TYPE student_varraytype IS VARRAY(255) OF NUMBER;
 --use of the type
 student_varray student_varraytype;
BEGIN
  SELECT student_id
   BULK COLLECT INTO student_array
   FROM student
  WHERE student_class = 10;
 --
 FOR i IN student_array.FIRST .. student_array.LAST
  LOOP
    student_varray(i) := i;
  END LOOP;
 END;
```

Is this the correct way of looping through the table collection and adding to the VArray?

If someone knows an alternative i appreciate if you could share views with me.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Do you really need to add the records to the VARRAY?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're trying to accomplish as your code makes not much sense ? What's the problem to use nested table collection (`type student_list is table of student%rowtype;`) ? In general the best practice is not to loop (but there's cases when it can't be avoided).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can BULK COLLECT into multiple collections:

```
SELECT student_id, rownum
   BULK COLLECT INTO student_array, student_varray
   FROM student
  WHERE student_class = 10;
```

And in your example you don't add an item to a varray, just index of the item in the associative array.